# Get data from md-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using Angular Material to make my new web app, I want to get the selected value from an `<md-select>` and the problem is that I am new to angularjs and how it works. If anyone could help me, it would be really appreciated.

**HTML :**

```
<md-input-container>
        <label>Rating</label>
         <md-select ng-model="userRating">
            <md-option><em>None</em>
            </md-option>
            <md-option ng-repeat="rate in ratings" ng-value="rate.abbrev">
                {{rate.abbrev}}
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get the value by using the $**`scope`** variable

In controller

**`console.log($scope.userRating);`**

Inorder to get the selected value on change , you can pass the selected to a function and display,

```
<md-select ng-change="Print()" class="inline-flex md-select-down" placeholder="Select" ng-model="model">
      <md-option ng-repeat="item in ratings" value="{{item.value}}">
        {{item.abbrev}}
      </md-option>
 </md-select>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.Print = function(){
        alert($scope.model);
}
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Gr98c49YA1sopFy9jHeQ?p=preview)**

Comment: Can't I use it like in the normal <select> ? Like the if selectedindex == 1 { function() }?

Comment: that is to check the selected value. you can use ng-change and call a function. check the demo attached

Comment: Hmm, and I would like to have if the selectedindex is "none", run a function and if not, run another function..

Comment: you can do with the same way i have mentioned

Comment: Can I use the ng-change on the md-option??

Comment: @TouficBatache no you can't

Comment: @TouficBatache check this demo https://plnkr.co/edit/Gr98c49YA1sopFy9jHeQ?p=preview

Comment: click the button my requirement , if there is no value it will run the first function else it will run the 2nd one

Comment: @TouficBatache Mark and upvote answer if it has helped